# Apply ErrorBoundary to a react project without root component

Tags: reactjs

My team is the progress of migrating from angularjs to react. Since the project is not started with react, it does not have a root component. We start to insert our react components into angularjs with react-component. Those react components do not have a common parent. Now i am trying to apply errorBoundary to my react components. One obvious way is to wrap every component with error boundary. The problem with this approach is that someone who codes a new react component later may forget to wrap the new component with error boundary. Is there a way to apply error boundary to those react components as a whole/

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You *could* run into some UX and/or performance issues wrapping *every* component with an Error Boundary. However, if it's something you still wish to do, you could monkey patch `React.createElement` to automatically wrap every component with an Error Boundary component before rendering. This will undoubtedly result in very poor UX though, since you'll probably just have a generic error boundary rather than context-specific boundaries that are actually helpful to the user.

- I have more about this in [a talk here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZF-XybpC5TM).
- And there's a great [post from Brandon Dail about this here](https://aweary.dev/fault-tolerance-react/).

If you're looking for a code example on how to do this, [here's a monkeyPatchReact function I wrote for React Chaos](https://github.com/jchiatt/react-chaos/blob/feat/overwrite-createElement/src/utils/monkeyPatchReact.ts). You should be able to create a function that passes a new `createElement` to overwrite React's `createElement` and then calls the original React `createElement` but with the children wrapped in your error boundary.

Alternatively, you could use the [built-in `React.Children.map`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html) to wrap every child with an error boundary.

Hope that helps. Cheers.